# Message "The content of this page was successfully republished" not always showing

Tags: experience-manager

I have installed Experience manager and it seems to work like it should, but there is something strange with the confirmation message when the page is published.

Sometimes this message shows after a successful publish, but sometimes it doesn't.

What could be blocking this message?

p.s. I need the message (actually the button in the message "Reload page") to update my page, since I don't use session preview and therefore the update preview button is disabled.

Comment: have you tried using firebug to see if there is a problem in the webpage?

Answer (score 4):

Today I was working with Experience Manager as well. I thought to myself that sometimes I just didn't see the notification, but maybe it was not there at all, as in your case.

Actually the page may not be published sometimes and that's why you don't receive a notification. Have you tried after finish editing (and publishing should be processed) to open the page, for example, in another browser and see if the changes you made are present? I believe that if there is a problem publishing it, it might notify you.